# select2 search match with typed letter in any position regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, jquery-select2

Is there a way to search for any matched letters in [select2](https://select2.org/)?

For example, if I have the following options:

```
<option value="MANGO">MANGO</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="APPLE">APPLE</option>
```

and if I type "mngo", is there a way to show "MANGO" option in the search result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is clear, it's adding a `.*` between each character and before and after all characters. You can change that wildcard as you please.

I tried to be the less verbose possible, was tricky and fun doing this.

```js
$('#select2').select2({
  matcher: function(term, text) {
    // If search is empty we return everything
    if ($.trim(term.term) === '') return text;

    // Compose the regex
    var regex_text = '.*';
    regex_text += (term.term).split('').join('.*');
    regex_text += '.*'

    // Case insensitive
    var regex = new RegExp(regex_text, "i");

    // If no match is found we return nothing
    if (!regex.test(text.text)) {
      return null;
    }

    // Else we return everything that is matching
    return text;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="select2" style="width:100%;">
  <option value="MANGO">MANGO</option>
  <option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
  <option value="APPLE">APPLE</option>
</select>
```